# Submatrix based on size vector

Tags: matlab, submatrix

It seems like this problem should be common, but I haven't found a good duplicate...

I'm implementing a level 2 S-function with a variable-sized multidimensional output. The state has to be in fixed-size Dwork vectors, so I zero-pad the input matrix to the maximum size allowed for the input and then reshape it to a vector.

When I reshape it back to a matrix for output, I need to trim it back down to the correct size.

The function needs to be general enough to support an arbitrary number of dimensions. The size of the output is stored in a size array.

For example, I may have a 500x500 matrix N, and a size array S = [40 25]. I need a MATLAB expression that would give me N(1:S(1), 1:S(2)), but it needs to work for any number of dimensions so I can't simply hardcode it like that.

Comment: Are you looking for m code or c++ code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution in m-code:

```
%your input
M=rand(10,10,10);
S=[2,3,4]
%generate indices:
Index=arrayfun(@(x)(1:x),S,'uni',0)
%use comma separated list to index:
smallM=M(Index{:})
```